# Why isn't the transform applied to both nodes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I'm attempting to draw some 3d projections to help explain a concept. I thought I'd use tikz transforms for that, but after a long time trying, I found that transforms don't really work when I use `\node` directly, but they work if I use `\draw (0,0) rectangle (3,2)` (code below). Could anyone explain to me why that is the case and, is there a way to make the transform work with everything inside the scope?

```
\documentclass[crop, margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    my node/.style={
      fill=none,
      very thick,
      draw=black!75,
      opacity=0.5,
      fill=#1,
    },
  ]
  \begin{scope}[cm={1, 0.5, 0, 1, (0, 0)}]
    \draw[
      my node=red,
      opacity=0.5,
    ] (0,0) rectangle (3cm,2cm);
    \node[
      my node=blue,
      minimum width=3cm,
      minimum height=2cm,
      anchor=south west,
    ] at (0,0) {};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And here's what it looks:

[image]

Comment: It appears that I need to use `transform shape`, but why is that the case?

Comment: Because [“you usually do not want your text to be scaled or rotated even if the main graphic is transformed. Scaling text is evil, rotating slightly less so.”](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#sec-17.7)

Comment: The reason is stated in the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) (currently [version  3.1.10] on page 375): "The most important aspect of the coordinate transformation matrix is *that it applies to coordinates only!*" This means, node shapes are not affected by such transformations. You need to specifically tell Ti*k*Z to also transform shapes.